# How do you undo a line undo in Vim?

Tags: vim

The <kbd>u</kbd> key undoes the last change and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> redoes it, but the <kbd>U</kbd> letter undoes changes on a line, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> doesn't redo them. Is there no such thing as a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> line redo key?

Answer (score 2):

From [`:h U`](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html?#U):

```
                                                    U
U                   Undo all latest changes on one line, the line where
                    the latest change was made. U itself also counts as
                    a change, and thus U undoes a previous U.
```